# Part of Popup calendar hidden behind iframe

Tags: html, ajax, iframe, calendar, popup

All respected members,

i am trying to insert a aspx page within iframe in html page as :

```
  <iframe  id="one" src="ElectLocoPerformance2.aspx" height="100%" width="100%" runat="server" scrolling="no" marginheight="0%"    frameborder="0"  /> </p>
```

Pgae is displaying well, however, AJAX popup calender is not visible fully as some part are hiddin behind the iframe.  Although dropdown list are visible fully.

My aspx code is as under:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffcc">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager> 

<table class="style3">
    <tr>
        <td class="style38">
            <strong>Trains lost Punctuality (Territorial)</strong></td>
        <td class="style43">
            From Date</td>
        <td class="style22">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtstrdt" runat="server" Contenteditable="false" Width="90px"/>
            <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"  TargetControlID="txtstrdt"  Format="dd-MMM-yy"  >
                            </ajax:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DateRequiredFieldValidator" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtstrdt" ErrorMessage="Name" 
                        Text="Can not be left blank" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" />

        </td>
        <td class="style63">
            <strong class="style66">To Date</strong></td>
        <td class="style30">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtenddt" runat="server" Contenteditable="false" Width="90px"/>
            <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server"  TargetControlID="txtenddt"  Format="dd-MMM-yy">
                            </ajax:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtenddt" ErrorMessage="Name" 
                        Text="Can not be left blank" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" /></td>
        <td class="style61">
            Territorial Railway</td>
        <td class="style65">
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="txtrly" BorderColor="Black" Width="90px" Height="22px" 
                CssClass="style62" >
            <asp:ListItem  Value="">ALL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CR">CR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ER">ER</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ECR">ECR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ECoR">ECoR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NR">NR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NCR">NCR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NER">NER</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NFR">NFR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NWR">NWR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SR">SR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SCR">SCR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SER">SER</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SECR">SECR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SWR">SWR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="WR">WR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="WCR">WCR</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td class="style60">
            <strong>Owning Shed</strong></td>
        <td class="style76">
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="txtshed" BorderColor="Black" Width="90px" Height="22px" 
                CssClass="style62" >
            <asp:ListItem  Value="">ALL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BSL">BSL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AQ">AQ</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="KYN">KYN</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ASN">ASN</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="HWH">HWH</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="MGS">MGS</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="GMO">GMO</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="WAT">WAT</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ANGL">ANGL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="GZB">GZB</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="LDH">LDH</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="JHS">JHS</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CNB">CNB</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AJJ">AJJ</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ED">ED</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="RPM">RPM</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BZA">BZA</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem  Value="LGD">LGD</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="KZJ">KZJ</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TATA">TATA</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BNDM">BNDM</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BKSC">BKSC</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SRC">SRC</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BIA">BIA</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BRC">BRC</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BL">BL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TKD">TKD</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ET">ET</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="NKJ">NKJ</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td class="style72">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSend" Text="GO" runat="server" onclick="btnSend_Click"/></td>
        <td class="style64">
            &nbsp;</td>
</table>
```

Is there any possibility to resolve this issue? please help.

Or suggest any method to put two or more submit buttons be placed in form teg for redirecting differnt pages based on date pickers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried positioning the elements then setting the `z-index` property on the popup calendar?

Comment: Try to recreate the issue and provide a link to the fiddle.